# Chrome extension - strange execution order

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a small Chrome extension
and in my **background.html** I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    var hash = '';
    var tab_id = -1;
    var block;

    tab_id = get_tab_id();
    //no myurl page is opened
    if(tab_id == -1)
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://myurl', 'selected': false});
        tab_id = get_tab_id();
    }


function get_tab_id()
{
    var tab_id = -1;

    //find the needed page and get id
alert('ins0');
    // get the current window
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win)
    {
    alert('ins1');
        // get an array of the tabs in the window
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs)
        {
    alert('ins2');
            for (i in tabs) // loop over the tabs
            {
    alert('ins3');
                // if the tab is not the selected one
                if (tabs[i].url == 'http://myurl')
                {
    alert('ins4');
                    //get tab id
                    tab_id = tabs[i].id;
                }
            }
        });
    });
alert('ins5');
    alert('tab_id: ' + tab_id);
alert('ins6');
    return tab_id;
}
</script>
```

The strange is that when I launch the extension - the order of alerts is the following:

```
ins0
ins5
ins1
tab_id: -1
ins2
ins3
ins6
```

So it looks like it is jumping from one part of the code to the other.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just trying to make sure you don't open more than one tab of the same?

Comment: nope, the task was different. I've already fixed it. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome API calls are asynchronous, so if you want to execute them in order you need to use callbacks. If all you need is to get newly created tab id then:

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://myurl', 'selected': false}, function(tab){
    console.log("created tab:", tab.id);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Your `get_tab_id()` function then should look like this:

```
function get_tab_id(url, callback)
{
    var id = -1;

    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs)
    {
        for (var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++)
        {
            if (tabs[i].url == url)
            {
                id  = tabs[i].id;
                break;
            }
        }
        callback(id);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var tab_id = -1;
get_tab_id('http://myurl', function(id){
    console.log(id);
    if(id == -1) {
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'http://myurl', 'selected': false}, function(tab){
            console.log("created tab:", tab.id);
            tab_id = tab.id;

            restOfCode();
        });
    } else {
        tab_id = id;
        restOfCode();
    }
});

function restOfCode() {
    //executed after tab is created/found
}
```

Comment: I need to create a new tab - just in case there is no such tab already opened. That is why I check all the tabs one by one. ALso I need to get tab_id of my page for the further processing.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I've already fixed that through using callbacks. Your info that chrome extensions are asynchronous was very helpful.